# Java How order a list of objects with sets of integers

Tags: java, generics, set, compare

I have a list of generic objects with some attributes and one of them it is a Set (treeSet) of Integers.

```
class GenericObject{
    Set<Integer> orderNumbers = new TreeSet<>();
    Other attributes...
}
```

I want to order this list of generic objects comparing the Set... example:

My actual List list;
GenericObject with Set --> 2,3,4
GenericObject with Set --> 1,2
GenericObject with Set --> 4,5
GenericObject with Set --> 2,3

I want order the list of object like that:
1) 1,2 
2) 2,3
3) 2,3,4
4) 4,5

I am trying to implements the Comparator of GenericObject and Overriding the method compare but I have not got it.

Thanks, I'll be waiting for your answers

Comment: Need to describe the way you want you order to work. Like 1,2 vs 1,2,3 ? 1,2,3 vs 2,3 ? Do you compared first number of each set, then the next number of each set and that's how you want your sort to work ?

Comment: Show the actual code please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `orderNumbers` is a `Set` the elements will be arranged in their natural order, so you can compare the first elements and size of it. Here is the comparator:

```
(a, b) -> {

    Integer nexta = a.orderNumbers.iterator().next(),
            nextb = b.orderNumbers.iterator().next();

    if( nexta == nextb ) {
        return a.orderNumbers.size() > b.orderNumbers.size() ? 1 : -1;
    }

    return Integer.compare(nexta, nextb);
}
```

**[DEMO](https://ideone.com/yJssuh)**

Comment: What is the reason to just compare the first element from each Set?

Comment: @user7 did you read the question carefully before downvoting?

Comment: I agree that OP's requirements are not clear. Since you are only comparing the first element from the Set, this won't work for [[2, 3, 4], [2, 3]] or vice versa. (You would consider these two as same but OP wants [2,3] followed by [2,3,4])

Answer (score 0):

In the `GenericObject` `Comparator` you will have to compare one by one the Integers contained in the `Set`s.
You should rely on the Integer comparable method but for the specific case (same elements but one additional), where the set with less elements should be placed before in the order.
It should be the most direct efficient approach in terms of time.

If performance is not a need (few list and few elements), you could accumulate the `Integer`s of the List in a `String` and perform a lexicographical comparison as finally that is what you need.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.TreeSet;

class GenericObject {

    private Set<Integer> orderNumbers;

    public GenericObject(Set<Integer> treeSet) {
        this.orderNumbers = treeSet;
    }
    // Other attributes...

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        List<GenericObject> list = new ArrayList<>();
        list.add(new GenericObject(new TreeSet<>(Arrays.asList(2, 3, 4))));
        list.add(new GenericObject(new TreeSet<>(Arrays.asList(1, 2))));
        list.add(new GenericObject(new TreeSet<>(Arrays.asList(4, 5))));
        list.add(new GenericObject(new TreeSet<>(Arrays.asList(2, 3))));

        list.sort(new Comparator<GenericObject>() {

            @Override
            public int compare(GenericObject o1, GenericObject o2) {

                String o1String = o1.orderNumbers.stream()
                                                 .map(Object::toString)
                                                 .reduce("", String::concat);

                String o2String = o2.orderNumbers.stream()
                                                 .map(Object::toString)
                                                 .reduce("", String::concat);

                return o1String.compareTo(o2String);
            }
        });

        System.out.println(list);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "GenericObject [orderNumbers=" + orderNumbers + "]";
    }
}
```

Output :

> [GenericObject [orderNumbers=[1, 2]], GenericObject [orderNumbers=[2,
>   3]], GenericObject [orderNumbers=[2, 3, 4]], GenericObject
>   [orderNumbers=[4, 5]]]

Comment: How will this work for [1, 30] and [12]? From OP, I *guess* the intended ouput is [1,30] followed by [12]